# Python / Pandas - Consider 'empty string' as a match during merge using multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I'm trying to merge 2 dataframes on multiple columns:`['Unit','Geo','Region']`. And, the condition is: When a value from `right_df` encounters an 'empty string' on `left_df` , it should consider as a match.

eg.,when first row of `right_df` joins with first row of `left_df` , we have a empty string for column:`'Region'` . So,need to consider the empty string as a match to 'AU' and get the final result 'DE".

```
left_df = pd.DataFrame({'Unit':['DEV','DEV','DEV','DEV','DEV','TEST1','TEST2','ACCTEST1','ACCTEST1','ACCTEST1'],
                    'Geo':['AP','JAPAN','NA','Europe','Europe','','','AP','Europe','NA'],
                    'Region':['','','','France','BENELUX','','','','',''],
                    'Resp':['DE','FG','BO','MD','KR','PM','NJ','JI','HN','FG']})


right_df = pd.DataFrame({'Unit':['DEV','DEV','DEV','DEV','TEST1','TEST2','ACCTEST1','DEV','ACCTEST1','TEST1','TEST2','DEV','TEST1','TEST2'],
                    'Geo':['AP','JAPAN','AP','NA','AP','Europe','Europe','Europe','AP','JAPAN','AP','Europe','Europe','Europe'],
                    'Region':['AU','JAPAN','ISA','USA','AU/NZ','France','CEE','France','ISA','JAPAN','ISA','BENELUX','CEE','CEE']})
```

[image]

I tried with the below code but it works only if the 'empty strings' have values. I'm struggling to add a condition saying 'consider empty string as a match' or 'ignore if `right_df` encounters empty string and continue with available match'. Would appreciate for any help. Thanks!!

```
result_df = pd.merge(left_df, right_df, how='inner', on=['Unit','Geo','Region'])
```

Comment: try ``left_df.replace('', np.NaN).combine_first(right_df.replace('', np.NaN))``, [`DataFrame.combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) but still you might find some missing values due to inconsistency in data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) inside a list comprehension and perform the
`left` merge operations in the following order:

1. Merge `right_df` with `left_df` on columns `Unit`, `Geo` and `Region` and select column `Resp`.
2. Merge `right_df` with `left_df`(drop duplicate values in Unit and Geo) on columns `Unit`, `Geo` and select column `Resp`.
3. Merge `right_df` with `left_df`(drop duplicate values in Unit) on column `Unit` and select column `Resp`.

Then use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) with a reducing function [`Series.combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) to combine the all the series in the list `s` and assign this result to `Resp` column in `right_df`.

```
from functools import reduce

c = ['Unit', 'Geo', 'Region']
s = [right_df.merge(left_df.drop_duplicates(c[:len(c) - i]), 
              on=c[:len(c) - i], how='left')['Resp'] for i in range(len(c))]
right_df['Resp'] = reduce(pd.Series.combine_first, s)
```

**Result:**

```
print(right_df)

        Unit     Geo   Region Resp
0        DEV      AP       AU   DE
1        DEV   JAPAN    JAPAN   FG
2        DEV      AP      ISA   DE
3        DEV      NA      USA   BO
4      TEST1      AP    AU/NZ   PM
5      TEST2  Europe   France   NJ
6   ACCTEST1  Europe      CEE   HN
7        DEV  Europe   France   MD
8   ACCTEST1      AP      ISA   JI
9      TEST1   JAPAN    JAPAN   PM
10     TEST2      AP      ISA   NJ
11       DEV  Europe  BENELUX   KR
12     TEST1  Europe      CEE   PM
13     TEST2  Europe      CEE   NJ
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there's some mismatch in your mapping, however you can use [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) method to handle empty strings:

```
# replace empty strings with nan
left_df = left_df.replace('', np.nan)

# replace np.nan with values from other dataframe
left_df.update(right_df, overwrite=False)

# merge
df = pd.merge(left_df, right_df, how='right', on=['Unit','Geo','Region'])
```

Hope this gives you some idea.

Comment: `update` will only work if the corresponding `indices` and `columns` in both the dataframes matches :).